# Can I make a free custom domain in a hobby app in heroku?

Tags: heroku, mern

Can I make a free custom domain in a hobby app in heroku?
I mean: Can I create domain named https://mydomain.c*om not https://my domain.herokuapp.c*om? and how?

Comment: Heroku is discontinuing hobby apps in November, FYI.

Comment: @O.Jones, Hobby ≠ Free. They're discontinuing _free_ dynos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you have your domain registered. Go to your project settings. Domain > Add Domain : Add your domain. Copy the DNS target and use in your hosting provider. (There are several tutorials on the internet for the most varied providers).

Comment: Kindasorta. OP will still need to register their domain somewhere, and that costs money.

Comment: Yep, just clarifying. The question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just wanted to emphasize that at least he would have to have a domain. It would be more coherent to say no. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not to be clear enough, thank you all!